# Keyboard Shortcut to show documentation in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Like in Jupyter notebook `shift+tab` is the shortcut to show documentation and `Tab` key for suggestions (.ipynb). Similarly in VS code what is the shortcut if I am using it for Python?
In VS code, while using .JS suggestions are coming as I type but for .py its not showing any suggestions.

Comment: When you edit the code, is the code auto-completion function available in Jupyter in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install an extension for python for autocomplete to work. Try this link to install the required extension and get access to IntelliSense.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Then ctrl + space should bring up intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

The pylance extension uses Pyright, a static type checking tool. Moreover it empowers "IntelliSense" experience of writing Pythong code in VS Code.

You should then be able to use the default binding ctrl+space for code completion. To see docstrings, just hover on the object you want information on.